# Groovy GStringImpl and String behaviour

Tags: string, groovy, equality

I've recently been reading about the behavior of `GStringImpl`s vs `String`s when used in collections in Groovy.

I understand that the reason this evaluates to false...

`"${'test'}".equals("test") == false`

is due to the symmetry requirement of the `.equals()` contract, however I was wondering if there was a reason the `GStringImpl` couldn't just be evaluated to a `String` immediately. So when I do something like this...

`"${'someString'}"`

I don't get a `GStringImpl`, I just get a plain Java `String` back, which I can immediately use as the key in a map, for example.

I know there are some workarounds, like

`String s = "${'someString'}"`

however stuff like this is a bit inconvenient, and the mix-up between `GStringImpl` and `String` seems to be a big 'gotcha' for Groovy newbies.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

*GStrings* are not evaluated inmediately to String because of some reasons, mainly related to lazy evaluation (which is quite good for logging) and templating. In [Strings and GString](http://web.archive.org/web/20150101122249/http://groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString) you can find a good explanation:

> `GString` can involve **lazy evaluation so it's not until the toString()
>   method is invoked that the GString is evaluated**. This lazy evaluation
>   is useful for things like logging as it allows the calculation of the
>   string, the calls to toString() on the values, and the concatenation
>   of the different strings to be done lazily if at all.
>
> GString is pretty handy when you don't want to use a template engine,
>   or when you really want full lazy evaluation of GStrings. When some
>   variable embedded in a GString, the toString() is called on that
>   variable to get a string representation, and it's inserted into the
>   final string.

Therefore:

> GString and String are two distinct classes, and hence use of GString
>   objects as keys for Map objects or comparisons involving GString
>   objects, can produce unexpected results when combined with String
>   objects since a GString and a String won't have the same hashCode nor
>   will they be equal. There is no automatic coercion between the two
>   types for comparisons or map keys, so it's sometimes necessary to
>   explicitly invoke toString() on GString objects.
>
> Unexpected conversion to String can lead to problems when code is
>   expecting a GString, as for methods in groovy.sql classes.

Comment: Can we dynamically extend GStringImpl class to automatically call .toString() on construction?

Comment: Calling `toString()` is quite verbose for a compact language like Groovy. Groovy folks really ought to add a shorthand for that. Slashy strings also produce GStrings, btw.