# Groovy Dynamically extend GStringImpl class to automatically invoke .toString()

Tags: groovy

On [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975465/groovy-gstringimpl-and-string-behaviour) @jalopaba explains in his answer that

> `GString` can involve lazy evaluation so it's not until the `toString()`
>   method is invoked that the `GString` is evaluated.

Can we dynamically extend the `GStringImpl` to invoke `toString()` on construction?

Comment: You can do: `String str = gstring` is that what you mean?

Comment: Ya but I have a lot of GStrings that I use as keys in a lot of maps. I don't wanna do assign to variable for everyone of them.

Comment: The whole point of `GString` is to substitute parameters when used. If you want to fix parameters at some point you should cast it to a normal `String` and not create a pointless subclass that would only break the assumptions about `GString`.

Comment: Why would that create break the assumptions? What are these assumptions? can you explain?

Comment: Are you having a problem using gstrings as map keys? I've used statements such as map."$someVariable" = "blah" without issues.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to override the put method of Map to check whether the key is GString and if yes, invoke the toString method? After that just invoke the original method with new key. Same for get.

Comment: How do I do that? How do I extend the put method of Map