# Groovy HttpBuilder json input trouble

Tags: json, groovy, httpbuilder

I am having issues passing json parameters to a web action. I know that the web action works at the specified url `http://projects.example.net/example/bugnetwebservice.asmx/MobileBuildAction`, as I have tested it with postman with the json parameters:

```
{
    featureIdStr: 31,
    actionStr: 1,
    comment: "Hello world"
}
```

and get the response:

```
{
    "d": "Succeeded"
}
```

Whenever I try to run it in groovy, however, I get this response:

```
Jun 10, 2016 9:54:25 AM net.sf.json.JSONObject _fromBean
INFO: Property 'value' of class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl has no read method. SKIPPED
Failure: 500
```

Here is my code:

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7.1')
import groovyx.net.http.*
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.*

def http = new HTTPBuilder("http://projects.example.net/")
def issueId = 31
def msg = "Build Failed"
def jsonBody = [:]
jsonBody.put("featureIdStr", issueId)
jsonBody.put("actionStr", 0)
jsonBody.put("comment", "${msg}: <a href='http://www.google.com'}'>Googles Job</a>")
http.request(POST, JSON) {
    uri.path = "/example/bugnetwebservice.asmx/MobileBuildAction"
    body = jsonBody

    response.success = { resp ->
        println "Success! ${resp.status}"
    }

    response.failure = { resp ->
        println "Failure: ${resp.status}"
    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Can you try changing the last `put` value to `"${msg}: <a href='http://www.google.com'>Googles Job</a>".toString()`? I think I've hit similar issues related to String vs. GString handling in HTTPBuilder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> jsonBody.put("comment", "${msg}: http://www.google.com'}'>Googles Job")

The "" in Groovy creates a Groovy String (aka the GString). GStrings are great - they allow that `${}` syntax - but they have some problems around serializing and deserializing themselves. There's an awesome [StackOverflow answer explaining what's up with that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18976592/224334).

Anyway, the short of it is, between that post and my own experience: anytime you're comparing or *might be* serializing your Groovy String, call `toString()` on it first.

I would consider writing your code like:

```
def commentValue = "${msg}: <a href='http://www.google.com'}'>Googles Job</a>"

jsonBody.put( commentValue.toString() )
```