# Value for a dynamically created property is null

Tags: performance, csv, groovy, jmeter, properties

In a setUp thread group I read csv file and create as many properties as I have records in my csv file:

```
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser  
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat  

def csvFilePath = "csv.csv";  
def reader = new FileReader(csvFilePath);  
def csvParser = CSVParser.parse(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader());  

def counter = 1;  

csvParser.records.each { record ->  
    def propertyName = "csvDataProp_${counter++}";  
    def concatenatedLine = record.values().join(',');  

    props.put(propertyName, concatenatedLine);  
}
```

In a main group I retrieve property values like this (in JSR223 PreProcessor, example for a 1st request):

```
log.info("Before accessing property - CSV Data: ${props.get("csvDataProp_1")}"); 
def csvData = props.get("csvDataProp_1"); 
log.info("CSV Data: ${csvData}");

if (csvData != null) {  

    def values = csvData.split(',');  
    def testNameColumn = values[0];  
    def testName = "Test:" + testNameColumn;  

    vars.put("testName", testName);  
    vars.put("endpointPath", values[2]);  
    vars.put("encryptedValue", values[3]);  
    vars.put("expStatusCode", values[4]);  
} else {
    log.error("CSV Data is null");  
}
```

But when I check logs I find:
Before accessing property - CSV Data: null.
CSV Data: null.

I added a debug post processors in the setUp thread and main thread and I can see all properties with their values, but for some reason when I try to retrieve the values in the code they are null.

Has anybody faced such problem? Could you help me with that, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy is a kind of strongly-typed language.

This expression of yours:

```
def propertyName = "csvDataProp_${counter++}";
```

produces [GStringImpl](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/GStringImpl.html)

and when you're trying to read it as:

```
props.get("csvDataProp_1");
```

you're passing a "normal" [String](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html) to the function.

As String and GStringImpl are different beasts you're getting `null` because the property doesn't exist.

The easiest solution would be explicit cast of GStringImpl to String like:

```
def propertyName = "csvDataProp_${counter++}" as String;
```

More information:

- [Groovy GStringImpl and String behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975465/groovy-gstringimpl-and-string-behaviour)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)